# How to search for specific text from a website, retrieve and use it with google app engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to retrieve basically this block of text from www.crossfit.com.

---

Monday 110516

Complete as many rounds as possible in five minutes of:

275 pound Deadlift, 3 reps

115 pound Push press, 7 reps

---

It's basically just the date (Monday yymmdd), and a short description of a workout. The site updates daily with a new workout. I want to write a google app using the python version that will pull the daily workout automatically. Where should I start? I followed along google's helloworld example and that's about as much as I know about html, python, and google apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of parsing the HTML yourself, use the already provided XML feed: http://www.crossfit.com/index.xml.

You can parse the XML feed in python 2.5 with [xml.etree.ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Comment: Instead of polling and parsing it yourself, you could use PubSubHubbub, too.

Comment: Thanks! feedparser is great. I had to read up on xml and rss feeds and I think I'm almost there. From the xml provided by website, the <description> "entry" of each <item> is often a long, oddly punctuated run on sentence/paragrapgh, what are some good ways to just extract the workout description, rep counts, and leave out all the rest?